# Placing jquery navigation buttons over slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Thanks man,

It took me a while but here's the code. I hope this works. I've never used this forum before.

My Code:

```
<html>
      <div class="container">
<div id="slides">
              <img src="_images/aqw.png" data-title="ALLIANCE QUARTETT WIEN: ">
              <img src="_images/aqw2.jpg">
              <img src="_images/eme.png">
              <img src="_images/eme2.jpg">
              <img src="_images/zen.png">
              <img src="_images/zen2.png">
              <img src="_images/cts.png">
              <img src="_images/cts2.jpg">
              <img src="_images/ag2.png">
              <img src="_images/ag.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

<!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

<!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

<!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 1000,
    height: 650,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 5000,
      swap: true
    }
  });
});
</script>
<!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#slides {
  display: none
}

#slides .slidesjs-navigation {
  margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}

a.slidesjs-next,
a.slidesjs-previous,
a.slidesjs-play,
a.slidesjs-stop {
  background-image:url(_images/btns-next-prev.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display:block;
  width:12px;
  height:18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

a.slidesjs-next {
  margin-right:10px;
  background-position: -12px 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-next {
  background-position: -12px -18px;
}

a.slidesjs-previous {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-previous {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}

a.slidesjs-play {
  width:15px;
  background-position: -25px 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-play {
  background-position: -25px -18px;
}

a.slidesjs-stop {
  width:18px;
  background-position: -41px 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-stop {
  background-position: -41px -18px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination {
  margin: 7px 0 0;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a {
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 13px;
  background-image: url(img/pagination.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
  background-position: 0 -13px
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -26px
}

#slides a:link,
#slides a:visited {
  color: #333
}

#slides a:hover,
#slides a:active {
  color: #9e2020
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

JS

```
(function () {
(function (a, b, c) {
    var d, e, f;
    return f = "slidesjs", e = {
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        start: 1,
        navigation: {
            active: !0,
            effect: "slide"
        },
        pagination: {
            active: !0,
            effect: "slide"
        },
        play: {
            active: !1,
            effect: "slide",
            interval: 5e3,
            auto: !1,
            swap: !0,
            pauseOnHover: !1,
            restartDelay: 2500
        },
        effect: {
            slide: {
                speed: 500
            },
            fade: {
                speed: 300,
                crossfade: !0
            }
        },
        callback: {
            loaded: function () {},
            start: function () {},
            complete: function () {}
        }
    }, d = function () {
        function b(b, c) {
            this.element = b, this.options = a.extend(!0, {}, e, c), this._defaults = e, this._name = f, this.init()
        }
        return b
    }(), d.prototype.init = function () {
        var c, d, e, f, g, h, i = this;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), a.data(this, "animating", !1), a.data(this, "total", c.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation", c).length), a.data(this, "current", this.options.start - 1), a.data(this, "vendorPrefix", this._getVendorPrefix()), "undefined" != typeof TouchEvent && (a.data(this, "touch", !0), this.options.effect.slide.speed = this.options.effect.slide.speed / 2), c.css({
            overflow: "hidden"
        }), c.slidesContainer = c.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation", c).wrapAll("<div class='slidesjs-container'>", c).parent().css({
            overflow: "hidden",
            position: "relative"
        }), a(".slidesjs-container", c).wrapInner("<div class='slidesjs-control'>", c).children(), a(".slidesjs-control", c).css({
            position: "relative",
            left: 0
        }), a(".slidesjs-control", c).children().addClass("slidesjs-slide").css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            zIndex: 0,
            display: "none",
            webkitBackfaceVisibility: "hidden"
        }), a.each(a(".slidesjs-control", c).children(), function (b) {
            var c;
            return c = a(this), c.attr("slidesjs-index", b)
        }), this.data.touch && (a(".slidesjs-control", c).on("touchstart", function (a) {
            return i._touchstart(a)
        }), a(".slidesjs-control", c).on("touchmove", function (a) {
            return i._touchmove(a)
        }), a(".slidesjs-control", c).on("touchend", function (a) {
            return i._touchend(a)
        })), c.fadeIn(0), this.update(), this.data.touch && this._setuptouch(), a(".slidesjs-control", c).children(":eq(" + this.data.current + ")").eq(0).fadeIn(0, function () {
            return a(this).css({
                zIndex: 10
            })
        }), this.options.navigation.active && (g = a("<a>", {
            "class": "slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation",
            href: "#",
            title: "Previous",
            text: "Previous"
        }).appendTo(c), d = a("<a>", {
            "class": "slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation",
            href: "#",
            title: "Next",
            text: "Next"
        }).appendTo(c)), a(".slidesjs-next", c).click(function (a) {
            return a.preventDefault(), i.stop(!0), i.next(i.options.navigation.effect)
        }), a(".slidesjs-previous", c).click(function (a) {
            return a.preventDefault(), i.stop(!0), i.previous(i.options.navigation.effect)
        }), this.options.play.active && (f = a("<a>", {
            "class": "slidesjs-play slidesjs-navigation",
            href: "#",
            title: "Play",
            text: "Play"
        }).appendTo(c), h = a("<a>", {
            "class": "slidesjs-stop slidesjs-navigation",
            href: "#",
            title: "Stop",
            text: "Stop"
        }).appendTo(c), f.click(function (a) {
            return a.preventDefault(), i.play(!0)
        }), h.click(function (a) {
            return a.preventDefault(), i.stop(!0)
        }), this.options.play.swap && h.css({
            display: "none"
        })), this.options.pagination.active && (e = a("<ul>", {
            "class": "slidesjs-pagination"
        }).appendTo(c), a.each(Array(this.data.total), function (b) {
            var c, d;
            return c = a("<li>", {
                "class": "slidesjs-pagination-item"
            }).appendTo(e), d = a("<a>", {
                href: "#",
                "data-slidesjs-item": b,
                html: b + 1
            }).appendTo(c), d.click(function (b) {
                return b.preventDefault(), i.stop(!0), i.goto(1 * a(b.currentTarget).attr("data-slidesjs-item") + 1)
            })
        })), a(b).bind("resize", function () {
            return i.update()
        }), this._setActive(), this.options.play.auto && this.play(), this.options.callback.loaded(this.options.start)
    }, d.prototype._setActive = function (b) {
        var c, d;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), d = b > -1 ? b : this.data.current, a(".active", c).removeClass("active"), a("li:eq(" + d + ") a", c).addClass("active")
    }, d.prototype.update = function () {
        var b, c, d;
        return b = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), a(".slidesjs-control", b).children(":not(:eq(" + this.data.current + "))").css({
            display: "none",
            left: 0,
            zIndex: 0
        }), d = b.width(), c = this.options.height / this.options.width * d, this.options.width = d, this.options.height = c, a(".slidesjs-control, .slidesjs-container", b).css({
            width: d,
            height: c
        })
    }, d.prototype.next = function (b) {
        var c;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), a.data(this, "direction", "next"), void 0 === b && (b = this.options.navigation.effect), "fade" === b ? this._fade() : this._slide()
    }, d.prototype.previous = function (b) {
        var c;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), a.data(this, "direction", "previous"), void 0 === b && (b = this.options.navigation.effect), "fade" === b ? this._fade() : this._slide()
    }, d.prototype.goto = function (b) {
        var c, d;
        if (c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), void 0 === d && (d = this.options.pagination.effect), b > this.data.total ? b = this.data.total : 1 > b && (b = 1), "number" == typeof b) return "fade" === d ? this._fade(b) : this._slide(b);
        if ("string" == typeof b) {
            if ("first" === b) return "fade" === d ? this._fade(0) : this._slide(0);
            if ("last" === b) return "fade" === d ? this._fade(this.data.total) : this._slide(this.data.total)
        }
    }, d.prototype._setuptouch = function () {
        var b, c, d, e;
        return b = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), e = a(".slidesjs-control", b), c = this.data.current + 1, d = this.data.current - 1, 0 > d && (d = this.data.total - 1), c > this.data.total - 1 && (c = 0), e.children(":eq(" + c + ")").css({
            display: "block",
            left: this.options.width
        }), e.children(":eq(" + d + ")").css({
            display: "block",
            left: -this.options.width
        })
    }, d.prototype._touchstart = function (b) {
        var c, d;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), d = b.originalEvent.touches[0], this._setuptouch(), a.data(this, "touchtimer", Number(new Date)), a.data(this, "touchstartx", d.pageX), a.data(this, "touchstarty", d.pageY), b.stopPropagation()
    }, d.prototype._touchend = function (b) {
        var c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = this;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), h = b.originalEvent.touches[0], f = a(".slidesjs-control", c), f.position().left > .5 * this.options.width || f.position().left > .1 * this.options.width && 250 > Number(new Date) - this.data.touchtimer ? (a.data(this, "direction", "previous"), this._slide()) : f.position().left < -(.5 * this.options.width) || f.position().left < -(.1 * this.options.width) && 250 > Number(new Date) - this.data.touchtimer ? (a.data(this, "direction", "next"), this._slide()) : (e = this.data.vendorPrefix, i = e + "Transform", d = e + "TransitionDuration", g = e + "TransitionTimingFunction", f[0].style[i] = "translateX(0px)", f[0].style[d] = .85 * this.options.effect.slide.speed + "ms"), f.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function () {
            return e = j.data.vendorPrefix, i = e + "Transform", d = e + "TransitionDuration", g = e + "TransitionTimingFunction", f[0].style[i] = "", f[0].style[d] = "", f[0].style[g] = ""
        }), b.stopPropagation()
    }, d.prototype._touchmove = function (b) {
        var c, d, e, f, g;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), f = b.originalEvent.touches[0], d = this.data.vendorPrefix, e = a(".slidesjs-control", c), g = d + "Transform", a.data(this, "scrolling", Math.abs(f.pageX - this.data.touchstartx) < Math.abs(f.pageY - this.data.touchstarty)), this.data.animating || this.data.scrolling || (b.preventDefault(), this._setuptouch(), e[0].style[g] = "translateX(" + (f.pageX - this.data.touchstartx) + "px)"), b.stopPropagation()
    }, d.prototype.play = function (b) {
        var c, d, e, f = this;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), !this.data.playInterval && (b && (d = this.data.current, this.data.direction = "next", "fade" === this.options.play.effect ? this._fade() : this._slide()), a.data(this, "playInterval", setInterval(function () {
            return d = f.data.current, f.data.direction = "next", "fade" === f.options.play.effect ? f._fade() : f._slide()
        }, this.options.play.interval)), e = a(".slidesjs-container", c), this.options.play.pauseOnHover && (e.unbind(), e.bind("mouseenter", function () {
            return f.stop()
        }), e.bind("mouseleave", function () {
            return f.options.play.restartDelay ? a.data(f, "restartDelay", setTimeout(function () {
                return f.play(!0)
            }, f.options.play.restartDelay)) : f.play()
        })), a.data(this, "playing", !0), a(".slidesjs-play", c).addClass("slidesjs-playing"), this.options.play.swap) ? (a(".slidesjs-play", c).hide(), a(".slidesjs-stop", c).show()) : void 0
    }, d.prototype.stop = function (b) {
        var c;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), clearInterval(this.data.playInterval), this.options.play.pauseOnHover && b && a(".slidesjs-container", c).unbind(), a.data(this, "playInterval", null), a.data(this, "playing", !1), a(".slidesjs-play", c).removeClass("slidesjs-playing"), this.options.play.swap ? (a(".slidesjs-stop", c).hide(), a(".slidesjs-play", c).show()) : void 0
    }, d.prototype._slide = function (b) {
        var c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m = this;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), this.data.animating || b === this.data.current + 1 ? void 0 : (a.data(this, "animating", !0), d = this.data.current, b > -1 ? (b -= 1, l = b > d ? 1 : -1, e = b > d ? -this.options.width : this.options.width, g = b) : (l = "next" === this.data.direction ? 1 : -1, e = "next" === this.data.direction ? -this.options.width : this.options.width, g = d + l), -1 === g && (g = this.data.total - 1), g === this.data.total && (g = 0), this._setActive(g), i = a(".slidesjs-control", c), b > -1 && i.children(":not(:eq(" + d + "))").css({
            display: "none",
            left: 0,
            zIndex: 0
        }), i.children(":eq(" + g + ")").css({
            display: "block",
            left: l * this.options.width,
            zIndex: 10
        }), this.options.callback.start(d + 1), this.data.vendorPrefix ? (h = this.data.vendorPrefix, k = h + "Transform", f = h + "TransitionDuration", j = h + "TransitionTimingFunction", i[0].style[k] = "translateX(" + e + "px)", i[0].style[f] = this.options.effect.slide.speed + "ms", i.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function () {
            return i[0].style[k] = "", i[0].style[f] = "", i.children(":eq(" + g + ")").css({
                left: 0
            }), i.children(":eq(" + d + ")").css({
                display: "none",
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 0
            }), a.data(m, "current", g), a.data(m, "animating", !1), i.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd"), i.children(":not(:eq(" + g + "))").css({
                display: "none",
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 0
            }), m.data.touch && m._setuptouch(), m.options.callback.complete(g + 1)
        })) : i.stop().animate({
            left: e
        }, this.options.effect.slide.speed, function () {
            return i.css({
                left: 0
            }), i.children(":eq(" + g + ")").css({
                left: 0
            }), i.children(":eq(" + d + ")").css({
                display: "none",
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 0
            }, a.data(m, "current", g), a.data(m, "animating", !1), m.options.callback.complete(g + 1))
        }))
    }, d.prototype._fade = function (b) {
        var c, d, e, f, g, h = this;
        return c = a(this.element), this.data = a.data(this), this.data.animating || b === this.data.current + 1 ? void 0 : (a.data(this, "animating", !0), d = this.data.current, b ? (b -= 1, g = b > d ? 1 : -1, e = b) : (g = "next" === this.data.direction ? 1 : -1, e = d + g), -1 === e && (e = this.data.total - 1), e === this.data.total && (e = 0), this._setActive(e), f = a(".slidesjs-control", c), f.children(":eq(" + e + ")").css({
            display: "none",
            left: 0,
            zIndex: 10
        }), this.options.callback.start(d + 1), this.options.effect.fade.crossfade ? (f.children(":eq(" + this.data.current + ")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed), f.children(":eq(" + e + ")").stop().fadeIn(this.options.effect.fade.speed, function () {
            return f.children(":eq(" + e + ")").css({
                zIndex: 0
            }), a.data(h, "animating", !1), a.data(h, "current", e), h.options.callback.complete(e + 1)
        })) : f.children(":eq(" + d + ")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed, function () {
            return f.children(":eq(" + e + ")").stop().fadeIn(h.options.effect.fade.speed, function () {
                return f.children(":eq(" + e + ")").css({
                    zIndex: 10
                })
            }), a.data(h, "animating", !1), a.data(h, "current", e), h.options.callback.complete(e + 1)
        }))
    }, d.prototype._getVendorPrefix = function () {
        var a, b, d, e, f;
        for (a = c.body || c.documentElement, d = a.style, e = "transition", f = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"], e = e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.substr(1), b = 0; f.length > b;) {
            if ("string" == typeof d[f[b] + e]) return f[b];
            b++
        }
        return !1
    }, a.fn[f] = function (b) {
        return this.each(function () {
            return a.data(this, "plugin_" + f) ? void 0 : a.data(this, "plugin_" + f, new d(this, b))
        })
    }
})(jQuery, window, document)
}).call(this);
```

I'm new to web and clueless using javascript. I'm trying to place a the navigation buttons (next, previous and play/pause) of the link below over the image but I can't figure it out!! I would really appreciate if someone could help? Also, is there a way on that same code of making it scale as the width and height change?

http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/

Thanks very much!

Comment: *"I'm new to web and clueless using javascript."*  Here's the first clue.  Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It's really helpful. Now, any chance of getting an solution for my issue?

Comment: @GonzaloFernandez would you mind posting your existing html and css so that we can tweak it for you (without having to go to the site and pull it down)?

Comment: @snumpy thanks a lot. I hope this is what you needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your Stylesheet

```
#slides .slidesjs-previous {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index:999;
}
#slides .slidesjs-next{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 10%;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant!! Thanks for your help! I just need to position it where I like and job done. I never thought a forum could be not just so efficient but also so quick!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bring some changes in the next previous css classes according to your requirement. That is: z index margin-top/top.