# SlidesJS trouble with height and button positioning?

Tags: javascript, css, button, slider, height

I'm currently building a website for myself and having some trouble styling it. By default the re are pagination buttons underneath the slider and a previous and next arrow. I managed to remove the pagination buttons, but am unable to position the next and previous button on top of the slider, these buttons should be vertical centered with the height of the containing images. I'm also having trouble with the height of the slider. The height should be the height of the images. The green part on my website is to much height.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks a lot for in the advance!

http://test.epicconcepts.nl

```
<style>
    /* Prevents slides from flashing */
    #slides {
      display:none;
    }

    #slides .slidesjs-container {
      margin-bottom:0px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      display:  none;
    }
    .slidesjs-previous.slidesjs-navigation {
        /* Styles for the Previous nav button */
        width: 32px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99;
        background-image: url("..//img/prev.png");
    }

    .slidesjs-next.slidesjs-navigation {
        /* Styles for the Next nav button */
        width: 32px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
        background-image: url("..//img/next.png");
    }

    .slidesjs-control {
        background: orange;
        max-height: 0px;
    }

    .slidesjs-container {
        width: 100%;
        background: green;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 700,
        autoHeight: true
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Hope this helps u...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564182/placing-jquery-navigation-buttons-over-slider

Answer (score 0):

I guess you since removed the slidesjs code from that URL, but I was having the exact same problem 10 minutes ago, so this is how I fixed it:

```
<div id="slides" class="slides">
  <img src="images/1.jpg">
  <img src="images/2.jpg">    
  <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation slides-button left">
    <img src="images/arrow-left.png" /></a>
</div>
```

I just put 2 images and one navigation button for the sake of simplicity. 
Then the CSS:

```
.slides { position: relative; } /* so the buttons are placed absolutety within this div */
.slides-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px; /* the exact position over the slides, from slide's (0,0) */
}
```

Remember, the navigation buttons have to be `<a class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation">` directly inside `<div id="slides">` or they won't work, don't put Divs in the middle.